# How to have dual write datasystem

Tags: hbase, databricks, data-migration, apache-phoenix

I am looking for a solution to write data into HBASE and the same to DataBricks. I can have a solution to add secondary indexes on timestamp column on HBASE (Phoenix supported) and another async process to read from HBASE and write data to DBX. But it will add read penalty on HBAE datasystem.

Can any one suggest a better solution instead of having an index added to the HBASE tables.

--Thanks

Comment: it heavily depends from where data is coming - common pattern is to put data into Kafka or something like that, and then have two write processes - one for HBase & another for Databricks. Just use two different consumer groups, and then each of the writers will be independent of other

Comment: The data is coming from Application.

Comment: Application works with HBase via some API implemented by another application, so you can add write to Kafka into that application